# JSP int values are casted to bool

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working on a project in JSP and I have a problem with the generated html.

Generated html: "1" is transformed into "Oui" (Yes in french) and "0" into "Non" (No in french)

```
<select id="privilegesRole" name="privileges" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Role 1</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">Role 2</option>
    <option value="Oui" selected="selected">Role 3</option>
    <option value="6" selected="selected">Role 4</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Role 5</option>
    <option value="Non" selected="selected">Role 6</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Role 7</option>
</select>
```

My JSP code:

```
<form:select path="privileges" multiple="true" id="privilegesRole">
    <form:options itemLabel="libelle" itemValue="id" items="${role.privileges}" />
</form:select>
```

Controller: in my controller values are good

```
RoleAdministration role = findBy....();
model.addAttribute("role", role);
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Edit: I have a BooleanFormatter.java but I do not see where it would be used

```
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BooleanFormatter implements Formatter<Boolean> {

   private String trueLabel = UtilMessages.getInstance().getString("common.oui");

   private String falseLabel = UtilMessages.getInstance().getString("common.non");

   @Override
   public String print(Boolean arg0, Locale arg1) {
       return arg0 ? trueLabel : falseLabel;
   }

   @Override
   public Boolean parse(String arg0, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
       if (Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals(arg0))
           return true;
       else if (Boolean.FALSE.toString().equals(arg0)) {
           return false;
       } else if (trueLabel.equals(arg0))
           return true;
       else if (falseLabel.equals(arg0)) {
           return false;
       }
       throw new ParseException(arg0, 0);
   }
}
```

We have changed the jsp code to:

```
<form:select id="privilegesRole" path="privileges" multiple="true" >
    <c:forEach items="${role.privileges}" var="currPrivilegeSelect">
        <option value="<c:out value="${currPrivilegeSelect.id}"/>" 
                title="<c:out value="${currPrivilegeSelect.description}"/>"> 
                <c:out value="${currPrivilegeSelect.libelle}"/> </option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

and that works, but we don't know why. If you have any explication we will be happy to read it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `privileges` object inside your `RoleAdministration`, look for the field `id`, according to [spring formatter documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/previews/ui-format.html) we can associate the any `field` with either annotation `Formatted` or implement `custom format annotation`.
In your case it can be like

`@Formatted(BooleanFormatter.class)` or
`@BooleanFormatted`

both on top of the field `id` inside the `privileges` object.

Comment: I've checked and there is no annotation like that.
And if there was the annotation, why only 0 and 1 are affected and not others ?

Comment: i dont think booleanformatter is used, because boolean formatter converts given boolean into locale specific string, check for any other formatter for numbers in your project.

Comment: Hum, we have IntegerFormatter which corresponds to the transformation of 0 and 1
After research IntegerFormatter is used in one xml file:
    <bean
    class="i2.application.cerbere.administration.web.controller.util.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean"
        id="applicationConversionService">
        <property name="formatters">
          <set>
            <ref bean="integerFormatter" />
          </set>
        </property>
      </bean>

Comment: now try to understand how the class ApplicationConv‌​ersionServiceFactoryBean fits into the picture, problem resolved.